# Is it okay to repost a reformulated question that is closed (or on hold)?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, reopen-closed, vote-to-reopen, reposts

If you

1. Formulate a question vaguely
2. It gets closed / put on hold for this
3. You take the comments to heart and reformulate it
4. It no longer gets attention but you have not enough reputation to trigger a reopen.

Then is there anything you can do? Is closing the question and stating it as a new question a legitimate solution? I have the feeling it is not, but did not find any info here on meta.

Comment: Btw, the question is http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1484899/15523

Comment: Come to think of it, maybe I should also write a feature request that one can start bounties on closed questions? That would be the perfect trigger for reopen, since you have to invest something into it. Don´t you think?

Comment: Reopen vote on your own question requires [only 250 reputation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes). Also, any non-trivial edit cause the question to reach the Reopen review queue anyway, so even user with 1 rep can easily put the question under the Reopen review, and if 5 users agree it will be reopened.

Comment: Ohhhhhh. I did not know. That comment would actually be a good answer to my question, Shadow Wizard!

Comment: I guess it´s just a weekend/monday phenomenon, that my question was not reopened. Or is the reopen review queue so full? (....or I still don´t understand what to fix in my question)

Comment: Jon just posted such answer.As for not reopened yet, not sure - either not enough users saw the review yet, or three users chose to leave it closed, which removes the question from review. [Here is recent example](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/506955) of a question that was reopened after being edited though.

Comment: Update: looks like you are out of luck: http://math.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/506302 (three users deemed the question as  not worthy of reopening, after three users has cast Reopen votes. You can try convincing two more in chat, or one mod, since voting to Leave Closed does not cancel existing Reopen votes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you make an edit to your closed post then it gets automatically added to the 'Reopen' queue in the Review section of the site.

Users with enough reputation (3,000) can then vote to reopen it if they feel it is suitable for reopening.

They don't have to find your question specifically, or see it in the main question list - it is just right there in the Review queue itself, already listed out for reviewers to approve / decline.

If you have done this and it doesn't get reopened and you still feel that it should be, then you can flag your own question for moderator attention and request they look at it an reopen if appropriate.

If you leave the question closed and ask a new one then you risk that one being closed as a duplicate of your original one. Which helps nobody and just adds to the overall 'noise' of questions on the site.

Comment: It is not at all appropriate to flag your post for reopening just because the community didn't reopen it from the queue.  Such flags are just going to be declined.

Comment: @Servy It's a last resort, sure. But it *is* an option once the poster has done everything they think they can. I'd rather the moderators be bothered by this and handle it behind the scenes than the same question be reposted to the site.

Comment: They're just going to reject the flag as something that shouldn't be brought to a moderators attention without even evaluating the question.  So you're just wasting your time and a mods time without even accomplishing anything.  Reposting the question is just going to result in it being closed as a duplicate.  The correct course of action is to *fix the question so that it no longer merits closure*, not to repost it or flag fora  mod, neither of which are acceptable.

Comment: @Servy It depends on the site size really. As a mod on UX we get the occasional flag of 'please reopen my question' sort of thing. I'll check the review history to see if it's been properly evaluated and then act accordingly. Sometimes if a question has been downvoted before closing then they get 'leave closed' flags by robo-reviewers who haven't reread the post. My priority is to the quality of questions on the site, so if reopening such questions helps that then I'd do it.

Comment: Regarding the first line - relevant changes: [Changing the question reopening experience](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367231/335251)