# Should I repost a question if the first edition was bad, has been fixed, and is still open?

Tags: discussion, edits, questions, asking-questions, question-quality

I asked a bad question. After many comments from other users and many edits on my part, it is now a good question. However, the comments are littered with corrections to older versions. Should I delete and repost this question, now that it is actually good, or keep the current version up?

This question is *distinctly* different than 
[Is it okay to repost a reformulated question that is closed (or on hold)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268100/is-it-okay-to-repost-a-reformulated-question-that-is-closed-or-on-hold)
, because I am asking about a question that is still open/has not been closed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I asked a bad question. After many comments from other users and many edits on my part, it is now a good question.

That is awesome! That is exactly what comments are for and is exactly why anyone, including the original poster can edit posts.

> However, the comments are littered with corrections to older versions.

Both the question and each comment have a flag option. You can either flag the post for moderator attention and state "The comments asking for clarification have been addressed in an edit. Please remove those comments". Or cherry-pick the comments and flag the ones that can go as *No longer needed*. A moderator will clean-up for you.

> Should I delete and repost this question, now that it is actually good, or keep the current version up?

No, why should you repost? It is pretty annoying for watchers of a tag to see the same question again without the edit-history. Seasoned users might assume bad intent. Your edits already put your posts on the top of the active tab already so it got views from that.

You never know if someone is already writing an answer. Deleting the question while in the middle of writing an answer is in my top 1 reasons to slap my monitor.

If your question already picked up downvotes it is an even bigger issue if you delete it. Negative scores on deleted posts still count in the quality-ban algorithm, and the fact that it's deleted can also count against you. Most users that end up in the q-ban do so not due to their visible posts but generally for their deleted history. And deleted posts never recover.