# Serious mistakes in question and deletion in case of no answers/comments

Tags: discussion, edits, deleted-questions

This is regarding a question I had posted on Math SE. After an hour or so, I realized that there were serious errors in the question (that may lead to misinterpretation). I was unaware of what the standard procedure is - to make edits or make a new question altogether. Since there were no answers/comments, I deleted and reposted the corrected version to avoid confusion and was flagged for the same reason. I was directed to this place to learn about the working norms in this regard.

Comment: Just to be clear, the [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/8966074) you received wasn't directing you to *this* meta site, but to the [Mathematics Meta](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/) site. This site serves as the network meta site, for reporting issues relating to the engine that powers the entire network of Stack Exchange sites, and questions only about one site aren't in scope here. Each site has its own separate meta site for discussing issues specific to that site, and working norms can be different on different sites.

Comment: Yes @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog. Thank you very much.

Comment: Related: [Should I repost a question if the first edition was bad, has been fixed, and is still open?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/329082/335251), [Is it okay to repost a reformulated question that is closed (or on hold)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/268100/335251)