# Suggested edits should show "edited" instead of "suggested" for the edit event in the timeline

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, wording, timeline

When viewing a post's timeline ([for example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/367231/timeline#history_68bccf68-cf76-4e45-85f1-7b6a22b9a0b0)), the edit event once a suggested edit is accepted says "suggested":

[image: timeline showing "suggested" for the edit event]

I remember it saying "edited" before. Saying "edited" also makes more sense, since this is the moment in which the *edit occurred*, not when the *suggestion occurred*. I suggested the edit at one point in time (starting a review process recorded as "Suggested edits", for the kind of review) and edited the question at a later point, when the edit was accepted. That second event was not a suggestion, it was an edit! Old suggested edits of mine (back when I remember it saying "edited") also say "suggested".

Please change it back to saying "edited" in the timeline.

Comment: The same issue also occurs for specific revision links.

Comment: My guess is that they're trying to distinguish an applied suggested edit from a regular edit from someone with enough rep. Maybe it should say "Edit Applied" or "Edit Approved".

Comment: Could this have something to do with the [adjustments to the reopen process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367231/273494)? There might be a reason in the future to distinguish suggested edits, edits, and edits that are intended to start a reopen review.