# Add "improve and reopen/leave closed" options to the question edit queue

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits, vote-to-reopen, improve-edit

Whenever a significant edit is made to a closed question, the editor can choose to let it enter the reopen queue (with the "*This edit resolves the original close reason and the question should be considered for reopening*" option).

Its reviewer is then offered three options:

- Approve and reopen
- Approve and leave closed
- Reject

[image: screenshot of these three options presented in the review queue]

In a recent review, the editor had (accidentally) introduced new mistakes. Doesn't it make sense to have the following two options added?

- Improve and reopen
- Improve and leave closed

An alternative to this approach is offered [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367247/422926): for the reviewer to have the ability to uncheck the '*This is a significant edit*' option.

Comment: Not to mention a "Reject and Edit" option. (No need to split that into two, as the normal Reject button has no divisions.)